# PHP Parallel network server for database access

Tags: php, mysql, networking, parallel-processing

I'm working on writing a multi-threaded network server to allow for non-direct database access over a network in PHP for security reasons.  The problem that I'm having is that PHP pthread has been discontinued in favor of a new method called parallel (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php).

The issue that I'm running into is the documentation states that everything must be passed by value, and that you cannot pass internal objects.  Well, sockets are internal objects as well as database link connectors.  However, the documentation also says that there are no restrictions in included files.  A socket is an internal type, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to bypass that.

In a traditional server, the main thread sits on the incoming socket and waits for clients to connect.  When a connection comes in, the main thread spawns a new thread with the socket information and goes back to listening.  Based on what PHP is doing now, that does not seem possible.

I've done a fair amount of searching on the internet and I have found -0- parallel examples that use networking with sockets or database connectors.  So, is this possible or do I need to write the server in another language, like C++?

Suggestions?

EDIT Jan 18, 2022 @ 23:30 PST (-8:00 UTC):

Here is the code that I have thus far...for a non-threading implementation.  The networking part does work as I have been able to test it.

FILE: config.php

```
<?php
/*

Configuration File

*/


// Network Parameters
const LISTEN_IPADDR = '0.0.0.0';
const LISTEN_PORT = 8476;
const MAX_CONNECTION_QUEUE = 1024;
const ACCEPT_MODE = 0;
const ALLOW_HOSTS = array();
const BLOCK_HOSTS = array();

// Operational Parameters
const MEMORY_MAX = '1GB';
const LOG_FILE = './vserver.log';
const DEBUG = false;

// Module List
const MODULE_LIST = array(
    'test.php',
);


?>
```

FILE: module.php

```
<?php
/*

Module Object File

*/


// All modules must implement this interface and also extend the
// class below.

interface moduleInterface
{
    const CMD_READ =        100;    // Read: Sends data back to client
    const CMD_WRITE =       101;    // Write: Writes data to memory
    const CMD_CHECK =       102;    // Check: Checks a value in memory
    const CMD_PURGE =       103;    // Purge: Removed expired data
    const CMD_AUDIT =       104;    // Audit: Data integrity check

    public static function initialize();
    public function process($socket, $command, $data);
}

class moduleObject extends Thread implements moduleInterface
{
    // These have to be set on a per module basis.
    const KEY = NULL;
    const ID = 0x00000000;

    private static $datastore = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        // $class = get_called_class();
        // moduleRegister($class, $this, self::ID, self::KEY);
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
    }

    public static function initialize()
    {
        $class = get_called_class();
        $object = new $class();
        moduleRegister($class, $object, self::ID, self::KEY);
    }

    protected function process($socket, $command, $data, $addr, $port)
    {
        switch ($command)
        {
            case self::CMD_READ:
            case self::CMD_WRITE:
            case self::CMD_CHECK:
            case self::CMD_PURGE:
            case self::CMD_AUDIT:
            default:
                $result = $this->processCustom($socket, $command, $data,
                    $addr, $port);
                if ($result == false)
                {
                    writeLog("Invalid command received from $addr:$port",
                        LOG__WARNING);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private function processCustom($socket, $command, $data, $addr, $port)
    {
        return false;
    }

    private function dataRead($socket, $data, $addr, $port)
    {
        return false;
    }

    private function dataWrite($socket, $data, $addr, $port)
    {
        return false;
    }

    private function dataCheck($socket, $data, $addr, $port)
    {
        return false;
    }

    private function dataPurge($socket, $data, $addr, $port)
    {
        return false;
    }

    private function dataAudit($socket, $data, $addr, $port)
    {
        return false;
    }
}



?>
```

FILE: main.php

```
<?php
/*

Main Server Program

*/

require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'module.php';


// ********************************************************************
// Iinitialize
// ********************************************************************

// This is to work around an issue with PHP on Windows machines.
// Turns out that the Windows Event Viewer has fewer log levels
// than Unix machines, so some of the log levels are mapped to
// the same number.  See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55129
// for details. We can do this since we are not using syslog.

// Logging Levels
define('LOG__EMERG', 0);
define('LOG__ALERT', 1);
define('LOG__CRIT', 2);
define('LOG__ERR', 3);
define('LOG__WARNING', 4);
define('LOG__NOTICE', 5);
define('LOG__INFO', 6);
define('LOG__DEBUG', 7);

// Global Variables
$LOGFILE = NULL;

// Set Parameters
ini_set('memory_limit', MEMORY_MAX);

// Array that holds all the class references.
// The data format of this array is as follows:
// ID => array(
//      'class' => classname,
//      'reference' => class reference,
//      'key' => access key,
//      'id' => class ID,
//  ),
$moduleRegisterArray = array();


// ******** Start server
openLogFile();
moduleLoad();
moduleStart();
initiateNetwork();
exit(0);



// ********************************************************************
// Functions
// ********************************************************************



// **** Error Handling/Logging

// Opens the log file.
function openLogFile()
{
    global $LOGFILE;

    $LOGFILE = fopen(LOG_FILE, 'a');
    if ($LOGFILE == false)
    {
        fprintf(STDERR, "Error opening log file. Aborting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    writeLog("Server started", LOG__NOTICE);
}

// Writes a log message to the log file or to the system console,
// depending on debug mode.
function writeLog($msg, $level)
{
    global $LOGFILE;

    switch ($level)
    {
        case LOG__EMERG:
            $type = '*****EMERGENCY*****';
            break;
        case LOG__ALERT:
            $type = '****ALERT****';
            break;
        case LOG__CRIT:
            $type = '***CRITICAL***';
            break;
        case LOG__ERR:
            $type = '**ERROR**';
            break;
        case LOG__WARNING:
            $type = '*WARNING*';
            break;
        case LOG__NOTICE:
            $type = 'NOTICE';
            break;
        case LOG__INFO:
            $type = 'INFORMATION';
            break;
        case LOG__DEBUG:
            $type = 'DEBUG';
            break;
        default:
            $type = 'UNKNOWN';
            break;
    }

    $date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
    if (!DEBUG)
    {
        if ($level != LOG__DEBUG)
        {
            fprintf($LOGFILE, "%s ::-%s-:: %s\n", $date, $type, $msg);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(STDOUT, "%s ::-%s-:: %s\n", $date, $type, $msg);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf($LOGFILE, "%s ::-%s-:: %s\n", $date, $type, $msg);
    }
}

// Handles socket errors
function socketError($socket, $func, $die)
{
    $code = socket_last_error($socket);
    $msg = socket_strerror($code);
    $txt = "Network Error: " . $func . " (" . $code . ") " . $msg;
    writeLog($txt, LOG__ERR);
    if ($die)
    {
        socket_close($socket);
        exit(1);
    }
}




// ******** Module Handling

// Load defined modules.
function moduleLoad()
{
    $path = './modules/';

    foreach(MODULE_LIST as $kx)
    {
        $fileMod = $path . $kx;
        $fileEx = file_exists($fileMod);
        if ($fileEx == true)
        {
            writeLog("Loading module file: $fileMod", LOG__NOTICE);
            require_once $fileMod;
        }
        else
        {
            writeLog("Module does not exist: $fileMod", LOG__WARNING);
        }
    }
}

// Starts off the module registration process.
function moduleStart()
{
    $classList = get_declared_classes();
    foreach($classList as $kx => $vx)
    {
        $position = strpos($vx, 'mod_');
        if ($position === false) continue;
        $vx::initialize();
    }
}

// Each module calls this so it can be registered.
function moduleRegister($class, $reference, $id, $key)
{
    global $moduleRegisterArray;

    $module = array(
        'class' => $class,
        'reference' => $reference,
        'key' => $key,
        'id' => $id,
    );

    $moduleRegisterArray[$id] = $module;
}

// The main server function.
// Does not return.
function initiateNetwork()
{
    global $LOGFILE;

    $func = 'initiate';
    $addr = NULL;
    $port = NULL;

    // Create the network socket.
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($socket === false) socketError($socket, $func, true);

    // Bind the socket.
    $result = socket_bind($socket, LISTEN_IPADDR, LISTEN_PORT);
    if ($result === false) socketError($socket, $func, true);

    // Now listen using an infinite loop.
    // The server will stay in this state until stopped.
    writeLog("The server is now listening on port " . LISTEN_PORT .
        " on address " . LISTEN_IPADDR, LOG__INFO);
    
    // Close the stdin, stdout, and stderr file descriptors.
    if (!DEBUG)
    {
        fclose(STDIN);
        fclose(STDOUT);
        fclose(STDERR);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        $result = socket_listen($socket, MAX_CONNECTION_QUEUE);
        if ($result === false) socketError($socket, $func, true);
        $spawn = socket_accept($socket);
        if ($spawn === false) socketError($socket, $func, true);
        $result = socket_getpeername($spawn, $addr, $port);
        if ($result === false) socketError($socket, $func, true);
        writeLog("Connection accepted from $addr:$port", LOG__INFO);
        process($spawn);
    }

}

// Test Function
function process($socket)
{
    $func = 'process';

    $msg = date('Y-m-d H:m:sP T') . "\r\n";
    $bindata = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(36);
    $msg .= bin2hex($bindata) . "\r\n";
    $result = socket_write($socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
    if ($result === false) socketError($socket, $func, true);
    socket_close($socket);
}


?>
```

This is just a framework that I've been working on.  Eventually, I want this to perform the following actions:

- Receive commands/data/queries from a client over the network.
- Process and convert the information into SQL commands.
- Send SQL commands to a database server.
- Receive results from said database server.
- Process said results.
- Send results to client over the network.

The actual data that goes over the network is in JSON format because it is platform neutral.  This is also the reason why I'm using PHP.  I probably could use Java, but the issue there is that the last time that I checked, Java support on *nix systems is sporadic at best.  The only other alternative that I can see is to use C++.  I haven't explored what Node.js provides, yet.

What I would like is the traditional server threading model where new threads are spawned when a client connection comes in over the network, and have it perform database processing based on the client's request.  So the software needs access to the network and the database at the same time.

Comment: Are you just looking to Fork out the processes?  And do you also understand how Gap locking works in SQL?  Forking processes may not improve DB efficiency as you'll get IO blocked anyway depending on index structure.  I can show you how to pass socket data on via forks (which will prob fit your needs) but it may not solve the issue re: databasing.

Comment: @MasonStedman Not really. I'm hoping to get some form of true threading in a server environment where I can spawn a new thread when a network connection comes in and that entire thread handles that one client's request, whatever it may be. So basically the traditional one thread per client request model. I don't think that I've heard of GAP locking before...at least it's not familiar. Remember, this software sits between the DB server and the network so clients don't send raw SQL directly to the DB server. So it must be able to access both the DB server and the network, at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these borrow from prior SO answers that I sadly didn't bookmark.

This method is if you want to just split your "threads" by IDs that you can generate in advance.  Make sure to close \ reopen all SQL connections prior to executing the following in either example as you don't want them shared.

```
$some_array_of_ids = [.....];

$max_children = 10;   // Max number of forked processes
$pids = [];           // Child process tracking array

foreach ($some_array_of_ids as $unqiue_id) {
    // Limit the number of child processes
    // If $maxChildren or more processes exist, wait until one exits
    if (count($pids) >= $max_children) {
        $pid = pcntl_waitpid(-1, $status);
        unset($pids[$pid]); // Remove PID that exited from the list
    }

    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid) { // Parent
        if ($pid < 0) {
            // Unable to fork process, handle error here
            continue;
        } else {
            // Add child PID to tracker array
            // Use PID as key for easy use of unset()
            $pids[$pid] = $unqiue_id;
        }
    } else { // Child
        echo "\nChild {$unqiue_id} has begun process...";

        .....

        echo "\nChild {$unqiue_id} has finished process...";
        exit(0);
    }
}

// Now wait for the child processes to exit. This approach may seem overly
// simple, but because of the way it works it will have the effect of
// waiting until the last process exits and pretty much no longer

foreach ($pids as $pid => $unqiue_id) {
    pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);
    unset($pids[$pid]);
}
```

If you actually want to stream socket data, there's a more elaborate method:

```
$some_array_of_data = [.....];

foreach ($some_array_of_data as $group) {
    $sockets = array();
    if (!socket_create_pair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, $sockets)) {
        die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    }
    list($reader, $writer) = $sockets;

    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid == -1) {
        die('cannot fork');
    } elseif ($pid) {
        socket_close($reader);
        $line = sprintf("{$group}\n", getmypid());
        if (!socket_write($writer, $line, strlen($line))) {
            socket_close($writer);
            die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
        }
        socket_close($writer);

    } else {

        socket_close($writer);
        $line = socket_read($reader, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

        $id = rtrim($line);
        $child_id = getmypid();
        socket_close($reader);

        echo "\nChild {$child_id} has begun process: {$id}.";
        
        ....

        echo "\nChild {$child_id} has finished process: {$id}.";
        exit(0);
    }
}

while(pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1);
```

While forking != threading, pthreads essentially was an abstraction layer over forks anyway vs true threading so.... meh.  Either way two different ways to handle this, depending on what your needs specifically are.

I would recommend the top one unless you really actually need to use a stream for something.  In which case I would need more details to give you better insight.  The bottom example should point you in the right direction if this is the case, and I can show you how to refine it to your needs if this code sample isn't sufficient.

Comment: Usually, when I write network software, I use either C or C++ depending on the requirements of the server. I have updated the question with more information.